# Query plugin for Google Sheets?

Tags: sql, google-apps, google-drive

I have several related spreadsheets in Google Drive. They include what would be foreign and primary keys in a database, so I can relate records across spreadsheets. Users need to create reports (new spreadsheets) by querying multiple spreadsheets. I can accomplish some of this with the `QUERY` and `IMPORTRANGE` functions, but these are kind of messy for a non-programming user who just wants to get data quickly.

I figured that others had already encountered this challenge and that there would be a plugin, but I’m not finding what I’m looking for. Is there an existing plugin or Google app that offers a user-friendly query builder that will search related Google spreadsheets and return results? (I don’t want something that just builds the query code and requires the user to copy/paste elsewhere. I’m looking for something that accepts input into a user-friendly query builder, builds and implements the query, and outputs the results.) I noted Google BigQuery, but it looks like that requires the user to do some SQL programming. Before I recreate the wheel, does what I'm looking for exist?

Comment: Have you already look at the G Suite Markeplace? Ref. [Use add-ons & Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)